# Eml to pst Redemption C# -> Null Exception RDOMail

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, outlook-redemption, eml, pst

i'm trying to create a program that conver eml file into a single pst.
i have write that command:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
RDOPstStore store = session.LogonPstStore(newpstpath);
RDOFolder folder = store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Item(directoryEmlFile);
RDOMail mail = folder.Items.Add("IPM.Note");
```

but at the command "RDOMail mail = folder.Items.Add("IPM.Note")" the system give me the null exception. can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: no it isn't is a problem with RDOMail object i think

Comment: The parameter is optional. Have you tried to call the Add method with a default value? Does it work?

Comment: yes i have try but the problem was the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to differ Outlook and Redemption objects.

It looks like you need to use the `GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` method of the Session class (Redemption).

```
 set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
 set redItem= Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(mail)
```

The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Items class creates and returns a new Outlook item in the Items collection for the folder.

Comment: I do not see any Outlook Object Model objects in the OP's code.

Comment: The code was added later, i.e. the poster edited the post. FYI The Items property of the Folder class exists in the Outlook object model.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the folder variable is null - if the folder does not exist, retrieving it by name (`RDOFolder.Folders.Item("foldername"))` will return null:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
RDOPstStore store = session.LogonPstStore(newpstpath);
RDOFolder folder = store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Item(directoryEmlFile);
if (folder == null) folder = store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Add(directoryEmlFile);
RDOMail mail = folder.Items.Add("IPM.Note");
```